# how to perform shearing of a rectangle in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, isometric

I am using OpenGL apis to obtain isometric view of Rectangle using SSR (Scale/Shear/Rotate) method. I am able to scale and rotate rectangle. But I not getting way as how to shear a rectangle. I am new to OpenGL. Please help.

```
#include <gl\glut.h>  // glut.h must come before gl.h and glu.h
#include <gl\gl.h>
#include <gl\glu.h>

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(20, 20);
    glVertex2f(20, 70);
    glVertex2f(70, 70);
    glVertex2f(70, 20);
    glEnd();

    glScalef(0.86,0.86,0.86);
    glTranslatef(200,0,0);
    glRotatef(30, 0, 0,1);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(20, 20);
    glVertex2f(20, 70);
    glVertex2f(70, 70);
    glVertex2f(70, 20);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}


void init()
{
    glClearColor(0.5,0.5,0.0, 0.0);
    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0,      // left
        800,  // right
        800, // bottom
        0,      // top
        0,      // zNear
        1       // zFar
        );
}


void main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB); 
    glutInitWindowSize(900, 1080);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("Simple");

    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    init();

    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: [glMultMatrixf](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glMultMatrix.xml) with a [shearing matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Shearing)

Comment: I don't know if this is your intention (it sounds like it is not from the description), but the order you are applying those transformations in is actually doing rotation, then translation and then scaling. You have to read OpenGL matrix operations from bottom-to-top because of the way post-multiplying column-major matrices works mathematically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a shear parallel to the x-axis by the amount `shear`:

```
GLfloat m[16] = {
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    shear, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
};
glMultMatrixf(m);
```

and parallel to the y-axis:

```
GLfloat m[16] = {
    1.0f, shear, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
};
glMultMatrixf(m);
```

When you compare this to matrices specified in mathematical notation, e.g. the [Wikipedia Shear matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_matrix) page, keep in mind that OpenGL matrices are specified in column major order.

Both of the above are for transformations in the 2D plane. I.e. the first one leaves the x-axis stationary, and shears the y-axis, while the second one keeps the y-axis stationary, and shears the x-axis. If you look at shear transforms in full 3D space, you get many more variations.